# Finding percentage memory utilization in pipelining architecture

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, mips, processor

I was solving problems from the exercise of the book "Computer Organization and Design" by Patterson. The problem reads like this:

> Consider stage latencies:
>
> ```
> IF      ID      EX      MEM      WB
> 250ps   350ps   150ps   300ps    200ps
> ```
>
> Consider instructions %:
>
> ```
> ALU     BEQ     LW      SW
> 45%     20%     20%     15%
> ```
>
> What is utilization of memory?

The solution given was:

> LW and SW instructions of pipeline use memory. Thus,
>     20 + 15 = 35%

However, I was guessing shouldnt we also consider stage latencies? That is , shouldnt this be:

$$
\frac{300}{250+350+150+300+200}\times \frac{35}{100}
$$

?

Comment: Latency only mean that there is a delay between the stages. But in the end the instructions **will** be executed. Thus only the amount of reads and writes count. Any separation in time due to the pipeline is irrelevant. Notes: 1/ It would help if you do not use 2 letter acronyms. I can guess LW (load word?) SW (Store word?) but IF, ID, WB ??  2/ LW and SW are *not* "stages of the pipeline."

Comment: (Yup LW and SW are load word and store word instructions, fixed now.) I doubt whether the problem mean "delay between stages" or "stage duration" by "stage latencies". The next sub-question (which I did not specified in above post) was:  Compare execution time in single cycle and pipelined system and solution was: (250+350+150+300+200)/350=3.57. So, by this, does it mean "stage duration" ? And if yes, should we use them in the calculation of memory utilization?